# How can I link my SEDE profile to my SE network profile?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

I'm using the same OpenID provider on SEDE as on the rest of the SE network (Google).

[My SEDE profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/5819/stijnherreman) doesn't seem to be linked to my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/89883/stijn?tab=accounts), and I didn't find a place to link it. How can I do it?

Comment: The closest this will ever be to being implemented is likely allowing you to authenticate against the Stack Exchange API from Data Explorer (i.e. the link would be one-directional, mostly), which is something I've been considering the benefits of. But going the other way would require Data Explorer to participate in the network authentication scheme, which it can't do.

Comment: @TimStone I see, I was a bit confused by how similar the top bar and login page are to SE sites, I thought Data Explorer was tightly coupled with SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a different system since Data Explorer isn't a QA site and doesn't even run on live data.  There isn't any way to link that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tag this as a feature request then.

Comment: @Stijn - out of curiosity, what are you hoping to accomplish with having them linked.  For QA sites it makes sense to be able to follow someone across sites since someone with good questions or answers on one site is likely to behave similarly on another, but Data Explorer is so unique that I'm not sure what advantage it would have unless they also added ability to query extra data about yourself.

Comment: It's mostly because I noticed there's a profile section on the Data Explorer and I figured it'd be nice to have it in sync with the rest of the network. One could argue that's not very useful, but then I'd wonder why there is a profile section at all.